# SSDT for visual studio 213 is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, SQL Server 2014 and I recently installed SSDT 2013 on my system (Windows 8). I'm not able to find SSDT UI for developing SSIS packages. Actually I'm new to SSIS so not sure how to open that SSDT for Visual Studio where I can start a project for ETL purpose. When I try to install SSDT from set, I get the below image but not able to find SSDT in my system. Please help. TIN

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0U8G.png)

Comment: For VS 2013, I'm almost positive you needed SSDT-BI for SSIS and such. You may want to check on that.  Alternatively, install the latest SSDT bits, make sure SSIS is selected, and you should have a VS 2017 or 2015 IDE that contains the appropriate BI Projects when you try to create a new project.  That's where you'd find SSIS - create a new project and select the BI options to get to SSIS.

Comment: I had to install SSDT for VS2013. Then it worked for me